# Merge two dataframes with conditions in pyspark

Tags: date, datetime, pyspark, conditional-statements, databricks

```
Df1:
+-------------------+
|               Date|
+-------------------+
|2020-07-01 00:00:00|
|2020-07-02 00:00:00|
|2020-07-03 00:00:00|
|2020-07-04 00:00:00|
|2020-07-05 00:00:00|
|2020-07-06 00:00:00|
|2020-07-07 00:00:00|
|2020-07-08 00:00:00|
|2020-07-09 00:00:00|
|2020-07-10 00:00:00|
+-------------------+
```

```
Df2:
+-------------------+----------+--------+--------+
|               Date|        ID|     Val|   f_val|
+-------------------+----------+--------+--------+
|2022-03-19 00:00:00|        34|     0.0|     0.0|
|2022-03-19 00:00:00|       108|     0.0|     0.0|
|2022-03-19 00:00:00|       155| 3070.61| 3070.61|
|2022-03-19 00:00:00|       193|22920.73|22920.73|
|2022-03-19 00:00:00|       211|   446.0|   446.0|
|2022-03-19 00:00:00|       321| 9314.16| 9314.16|
|2022-03-19 00:00:00|       362|  391.01|  391.01|
|2022-03-19 00:00:00|       368|    1.81|    1.81|
|2022-03-19 00:00:00|       375|    5.08|    5.08|
|2022-03-19 00:00:00|       530| 2444.76| 2444.76|
+-------------------+----------+--------+--------+
```

Both the DataFrames have `Date` starting at 2022-03-19 and ending at 2020-07-01. `Df1` contains a series of unique values from end to start date. However, `Df2` is rather very large dataset with same dates over multiple rows till 2020-07-01. `Date` of `Df2` has only 186 distinct values, and `Date` of `Df1` has 626.
With PySpark in Databricks, what I am trying to achieve here is, merge `Date` columns of `Df1` and `Df2` including all the missing dates in `Df2`, but `Df2` should fill the newly acquired rows with the previous row values.

Here is a sample of data when filtered over `ID`:

```
+-------------------+----------+--------+--------+
|               Date|        ID|     Val|   f_val|
+-------------------+----------+--------+--------+
|2022-03-11 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|    -8.0|81111.73|
|2022-03-07 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|   17.94|81129.67|
|2022-02-27 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|    20.0|81149.67|
|2021-01-25 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|    40.0|81189.67|
|2021-10-22 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|   89.06|81278.73|
|2021-10-18 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|   10.89|81289.62|
|2021-10-15 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|    60.0|81349.62|
|2021-09-22 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|  -250.0|81099.62|
+-------------------+----------+--------+--------+
```

And final expectation is:

```
+-------------------+----------+--------+--------+
|               Date|        ID|     Val|   f_val|
+-------------------+----------+--------+--------+
|2022-03-11 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|    -8.0|81111.73|
|2022-03-10 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|    -8.0|81111.73|
|2022-03-09 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|    -8.0|81111.73|
|2022-03-08 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|    -8.0|81111.73|
|2022-03-07 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|   17.94|81129.67|
|2022-03-06 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|   17.94|81129.67|
|2022-03-05 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|   17.94|81129.67|
|2022-03-04 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|   17.94|81129.67|
|2022-03-03 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|   17.94|81129.67|
|2022-03-02 00:00:00|   Ax3838J|   17.94|81129.67|
       .                   .         .       .
       .                   .         .       .
+-------------------+----------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import last
import sys

# first join the dataframes with left join. Keep df1 at the left side as it contains data for all the dates.

joined_df = df1.join(df2, df1.date ===  df2.date, "left")

# define the window
window = Window.orderBy('date')\
               .rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)

# define the fill forward columns
filled_column_id = last(joined_df['ID'], ignorenulls=True).over(window)
filled_column_Val = last(joined_df['Val'], ignorenulls=True).over(window)
filled_column_fval = last(joined_df['f_val'], ignorenulls=True).over(window)

# replace the existing columns with filled columns
joined_filled_df = joined_df.withColumn('ID',  filled_column_id).withColumn('Val',  filled_column_Val).withColumn('f_val',  filled_column_fval)
```

Comment: for 'ID', 'Val', and 'f_val', I am getting only null values in joined_filled_df